# Оборвана цитата из Апокалипсиса; поможете разобраться?

Tags: цитирование

Св. Андрей Кессарийский о фразе «грядет с облаками» пишет так:

> Здесь Он, закланный как агнец, приидет во славе Отчей как Судия, на
>   облаках, или силах бесплотных, или подобных тому облаку, которое на
>   горе Фавор осенило Его с апостолами.

У меня в тексте:

> Перед нами практически эмблема, к ней прилагаются строки из Откровения
>   Иоанна: *Здесь Он, закланный как агнец, приидет во славе Отчей как
>   Судия, на облаках, или силах бесплотных.* И Агнец на престоле словно
>   закланный, и во славе пред нами Сын Божий, и **силы бесплотные парят
>   вверху триумфальной арки – четыре ангела**, по сторонам от них
>   тетраморф – те самые апокалиптические существа – Орел, Телец, Лев и
>   человек с ангельскими крыльями, которых мы уже встречали в капелле
>   папы Сильвестра.

Если цитату оборвать на *силах бесплотных*, да ещё с точкой в конце,

получается уточнение к *облакам*, а вовсе не указание на тетраморф?

Кто в Откровении *силы бесплотные*?

Comment: Силы бесплотные — чины ангельские, воинство из 9 чинов.

Comment: На вопрос ответь, ПО-ЖА-ЛУЙ-СТА!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Галина, в тексте автора всё верно, ничего не надо менять, автор перечисляет всё, что изображено, это  практически эмблема: агнец - символ жертвы, Сын Божий и символ его присутствия - облако и ангелы (силы бесплотные), и тетраморф.

Он, закланный как агнец, приидет во славе Отчей как Судия, на облаках, или силах бесплотных. - эта фраза напоминает, что о присутствии Сына Божия возвещают или облака, или ангелы. В разных текстах по-разному описывается, как он появляется - то восседающим на облаках, то несомым ангелами, то в большом облаке, а оттуда глас Бога: "Это Сын мой..."

Ангелы - низший чин сил бесплотных, они нам даются для охраны, они и Сына Божьего несут на своих крыльях, здесь их 4, не будут же всех рисовать, это символ.

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо! Вот, что меня пуще всего смущает: *на облаках, или силах бесплотных* - и точка, обрывающая цитату. А у Кессарийского три составных: облака - силы бесплотные - облако как с Фавора. Что тогда делать в моей цитате: убрать зап перед *или*, поставить отточие в конце?

Comment: Можно поставить перед точкой  знак пропуска - многоточие в  угловых скобках < ... >

Answer (score 1):

Силы бесплотные — бесчисленное ангельское воинство. Тире в предложенном тексте надо удалить.

*... И силы бесплотные парят вверху триумфальной арки, а четыре ангела, по сторонам...*

Answer (score 1):

1) **Силы бесплотные**: Небесная иерархия состоит из трех ликов. Каждый лик имеет три чина. Высший лик состоит из серафимов, херувимов и престолов; средний – из господствий, сил и властей; низший – из начал, архангелов и **ангелов**. http://pravicon.com/info-901

2) Он, закланный как агнец, приидет во славе Отчей как Судия, (1) на облаках, **или** (2) силах бесплотных, **или** (3) подобных тому облаку, которое на горе Фавор осенило Его с апостолами.

Союз ИЛИ – повторяющийся, поэтому ставятся запятые. Если прервать цитату, то повторения не будет, запятая будет обозначать **пояснение, а не разделение**. Тогда облака могут восприниматься неверно, как силы бесплотные.

**Может быть, поставить хотя бы многоточие?** А запятую убирать нехорошо, **это же цитата.**

3) ...и **силы бесплотные** парят вверху триумфальной арки – **четыре ангела**...

Здесь всё нормально, четыре ангела являются представителями  сил бесплотных.

Comment: Жасминочка, это очень сложный и важный момент для книги - осрамиться ж можно! Людмила глубоко "в теме", но и её ответ не принёс мне желанной ясности. Шлю автору СПЕЦКАРАУЛ, все Ваши рассуждения - отдельным письмом: пусть размышляет, в каких дебрях очутился.